# user defined function not working in Angular Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

I defined a function calc inside controller, It is working fine while testing in browser but if i convert it into apk using cordova, it is not working. Even that whole controller itself is not working i tried it with a $scope variable. anyone have any idea why this is happening and how i can implement it.

```
$scope.addItems = function(singleItem){
    $scope.items = $scope.items + {
        item_name:singleItem.item_name,
        item_price:singleItem.item_price
    }
    calc();
}

function calc(){
    for(item of $scope.items){
        $scope.total = $scope.total + item.item_price; 
    }
    $scope.percent = ( 4 / 100 ) * $scope.total;
    $scope.subTotal = $scope.total + $scope.percent;
}
```

Instead of defining function directly i assigned it to variable and called it its not working, i also used $timeout function but same thing.I think for loop is causing trouble is there anyother way to iterate thru items in array

Comment: it's difficult to say anything from this. Can you share more of your code?

Comment: Can you debug your app with Chrome devtools see if there are any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya its for( of ){} loop is the reason, i tried with for(;;){} loop and now its working fine. thank you guys :)